# Dynamic query based on user selection

Tags: sql, dynamic, dynamic-sql

How can I generate a dynamic query based on user selection of data. I.E.
Table 1 has basic personnel data: name, social sec num... table 2 has address info: addr, city, state, zip
and table three has a work history of contracts that have been worked.

The user has choice of data to return:
Name, Address, Current contract, current name of place contracted, etc...

I have presented them with the list of options and I am storing in the database where the information is - tableName and fieldName ...

But I am not sure how to compile the data into a query dynamically. I get dynamic sql but this is a question of structure and retrieval.

Anyone done something like this or no a place to look?

Comment: Do you have to return one dataset? If you don't then i would have one table returned for each bit of the query as it will be more efficient and easier to read. If you need to get all of them returned in one; there are lots of DSQL examples on stack that will get you going.

Comment: Once I get the data, I throw it into XML and fill in a PDF form. The issue is getting the data with the appropriate JOIN and WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to feed this to a report all the time, I would suggest returning all the data to your report regardless, and then dynamically hiding the columns you don't need in the front-end application.  That is generally easier.

If you absolutely have to do it from the SQL side, you could do something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @paramDisplayName = 1 THEN Name ELSE NULL END AS Name,
    CASE WHEN @paramDisplayAddress = 1 THEN Address ELSE NULL END AS Address
    ...
    ...
    ...
FROM 
    Wherever
```

This would still return the column, though it would be empty.